# Turn recursive into iterative code

Tags: c#, recursive-query

I want to "transform" recursive code into iterative code. The example is:

```
 public int CalcTime(double AnnualIncome, int Time, double Value)
 {
     if (AnnualIncome / 12 > Value / Time) 
         return Time;
     else
         return CalcTime(AnnualIncome, Time + 1, Value);
 }
```

I tried but could not...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Need clarification on "transform" and "example" in your statement above. Do you simply want to restate the example above iteratively, or are you looking for a means of programmatically transforming the sample source code into an iterative example?

Comment: What's wrong with it how it is?

Comment: @woz easy to blow the stack doing that

Comment: Side-note: By convention parameters and local variables should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Good point @CodesInChaos; updated my answer to include a best practice version as well as the original direct equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
public int CalcTime(double AnnualIncome, int Time, double Value)
{
    while (AnnualIncome / 12 <= Value / Time) 
    {
        Time++;
    }
    return Time;
}
```

Also as @CodesInChaos points out in the comments above, best practice dictates lower case variable names:

```
public int CalcTime(double annualIncome, int time, double value)
{
    while (annualIncome / 12 <= value / time) 
    {
        time++;
    }
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Looks correct for sane input values. Might differer if `AnnualIncome` or `Value` isn't finite or if `Time<=0` (`a<=b` and `!(a>b)` aren't equivalent). But the correct solution for that is parameter validation.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion from recursive to iterative is most easily done by emulating the CPU natural call stack with your own stack. This is valid for problems that are naturally solved with a recursive function. (not saying this is the most correct approach)

In this case, something like this : 
(please note that i don't expect this code to either compile or to run as it should, it is just an example of how I believe this should be done)

```
Stack stack;
int time = 1; 
stack.add(time);

while(!stack.isEmpty)
{
   currentTime = stack.pop();

   if(AnnualIncome / 12 > Value / currentTime )
        return currentTime ;
   else
   {
        stack.push(time+1);
   }
}
```